# Selenium grid and Jenkins configuration

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, selenium-grid

I have downloaded Selenium Grid plugin for Jenkins, and I have two nodes running:

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role node -hub http://jenkins.bla.bla.com:4444/grid/register.

In Jenkins, in Selenium Grid tab I can see the two nodes connected:

> http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:5555 (*firefox 5/5, *googlechrome 5/5, *iexplore 1/1, chrome 5/5, firefox 5/5, internet explorer 1/1)
>
> http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:5555 (*firefox 5/5, *googlechrome 5/5, *iexplore 1/1, chrome 5/5, firefox 5/5, internet explorer 1/1)

When I try to build my project, nothing happens, because jenkins doesn't find any connected nodes.It's the same message when you're not running in grid, and no slaves are connected:

> #361 (pending—Waiting for next available executor)

I would like to ask the following:
1.Do we need to run the the script that initiates the slave-master connection when we try to run on selenium grid:

> java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl

2.Do we need to have the *selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar* installed on jenkins, or does it come with the plugin?

3.Is there an example of somehow with the whole process?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium server doesn't come with the plugin as far as I am aware. If you're looking for an example of how to set this all up, there is quite a nice PDF available at https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/downloads/Distributed_Testing_with_Selenium_Grid.pdf showing how to set up Selenium grid and configure Jenkkns to work with it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have read this pdf, and it implies that once you have installed the plugin, no other actions are needed to be done in the hub. Meaning that you don't need to run
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -port 4444 -role hub`
This can be also verified, by accessing:
`http://jenkins.bla.bla.com:4444` , where you actually see the nodes in console.
So why no job is started?

Answer (score 0):

with regards to https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/downloads/Distributed_Testing_with_Selenium_Grid.pdf
The above pdf is really good; however the section :

**Creating and executing Selenium script in parallel with Python** provides following methods
 1) using glob function
 2) nosetests function ( i tried this and it really works great for me)
 3) integration with jenkins
 - i seriously have no clue about this section ....and i think explanation is  insufficient .