# Cannot register node in selenium grid jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins, appium, selenium-grid, parallel-testing

Can anybody tell me how to configure selenium grid plugin in Jenkins? I am using appium for parallel execution using JSON. I have created the JSON in the plugin, but am not able to register start appium as nodes.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/a/30236714/1650738 which directs to a pdf having information on how to set up the Selenium Grid. You will have to set up nodes once you have set up the Grid.